# jQuery fancybox close button is missing "X" in mac os

Tags: jquery, html, css, macos, fancybox

Currently I am working in this site [Rentmesh](http://rentmesh.com/)

If you click on the match me button on the right top of the site, you can see a Jquery popup box. 
But in Mac OS the close button of this pop up is missing the "X" symbol inside it.
It is working from all browser in my windows system.
Currently I don't have a Mac system to check this. 
Can anyone please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.fancybox-skin .fancybox-item 
    {
        background-size: contain;
    }
```

First it was like this

[image]

Then I changed  `background-size: contain;`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of fancybox this css class is caled    `.fancybox-close`

So this would be `.fancybox-close { background-size: contain; }`